# Probability mass function of $M=\min\{X_¡: 1≤i≤ n\}$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots, X_n$ be independent random variables with $X_i$ having probability mass function

$$ P(X_i = k) = \left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)^k \frac{1}{i+1} $$

for all $k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$ and for all $i = 1, 2, \cdots, n$. Let

$$M=\min\{X_i: 1 \leq i \leq n\}.$$

Then derive the probability mass function of $M$. Please suggest me how to find me the $\text{pmf}$ of $M$.

Comment: One possible approach is to note $P(M \ge m) = P(X_1 \ge m) P(X_2 \ge m) \cdots P(X_n \ge m)$, and compute each $P(X_i \ge m)$ term separately. Then, $P(M=m) = P(M \ge m) - P(M \ge m+1)$. Not sure if this is the easiest approach though.

Comment: @angryavian. I am failed. Please sir elaborate your comment explicitly.

Comment: The above comment should work. Notice that if $p\in(0,1)$ and $\mathsf{P}(X = k) = (1-p)^k p$ for all $k \geq 0$, then $$ \mathsf{P}(X \geq m) = \sum_{k=m}^{\infty} (1-p)^k p = (1-p)^m. $$ So $\mathsf{P}(X_i \geq m) = \left(\frac{i}{i+1}\right)^m$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Sorry but why do you refuse to follow @angryavian's precise suggestion?

Comment: So now I have to put $P(X_i≥m)$ for all $i$ and then I will get $P(X≥m)$ and then separately $P(X=m)$ will automatically generate which is the required $pmf$. Is this the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $X\sim\mathrm{Geo}(p)$ and $Y\sim\mathrm{Geo}(q)$ are independent, then for each nonnegative integer $k$,
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X\wedge Y>k) &= \mathbb P(X>k,Y>k)\\
&= \mathbb P(X>k)\mathbb P(Y>k)\\
&= (1-p)^{k+1}(1-q)^{k+1},
\end{align}
so
$$
\mathbb P(X\wedge Y\leqslant k)  = 1 - ((1-p)(1-q))^{k+1},
$$
and hence $X\wedge Y\sim\mathrm{Geo}(1-(1-p)(1-q))$.
It follows that $$\bigwedge_{i=1}^n X_i \sim\mathrm{Geo}(1-\rho),$$
where
\begin{align}
\rho= \prod_{i=1}^n \frac i{i+1} = \frac1{n+1},
\end{align}
that is,
$$
\mathbb P\left(\bigwedge_{i=1}^n X_i = k\right) = \left(\frac1{n+1}\right)^k\frac n{n+1}.
$$